# How can I set HINSTANCE (Rust windows API) to NULL

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, windows-rs

I'm using windows-rs (version 0.52.0). I wanted to capture certain events (in my case, a keyboard input) for the entire system (by that I mean not limited to a single window thread). To achieve it, I've set the last argument, `dwThreadId` to `0` as the [Microsoft learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) states:

> The identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated. For desktop apps, if this parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread.

Which from what I understand `hMod` is not needed in my case, therefor I wanted to set it to `NULL`.

> The `hMod` parameter must be set to `NULL` if the `dwThreadId` parameter specifies a thread created by the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process.

Code below is a minimum replication for this problem

```rust
use windows::Win32::{UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{SetWindowsHookExA, WH_MOUSE}, Foundation::{WPARAM, LRESULT, LPARAM, HINSTANCE}};

unsafe extern "system" fn callback(code: i32, param: WPARAM, lpdata: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    LRESULT(0)
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{:?}", SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE, Some(callback), std::ptr::null_mut::<HINSTANCE>(), 0));
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get when running the code.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `*mut HINSTANCE: CanInto<HINSTANCE>` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:8:70
     |
8    |         println!("{:?}", SetWindowsHookExA(WH_MOUSE, Some(callback), std::ptr::null_mut::<HINSTANCE>(), 0));
     |                          -----------------                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `CanInto<HINSTANCE>` is not implemented for `*mut HINSTANCE`
     |                          |
     |                          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the trait `CanInto<HMODULE>` is implemented for `HINSTANCE`
     = note: required for `*mut HINSTANCE` to implement `IntoParam<HINSTANCE, CopyType>`
```

How can I set the `hMod` to be `NULL`?

I've tried setting the `hMod` variable to `std::ptr::null_mut::<HINSTANCE>()` and `HINSTANCE(0)`.

The first one is a problem with requirement of the `IntoParam` trait which I couldn't find much information for. The second one returns an error result of `Err(Error { code: HRESULT(0x80070594), message: "Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle." })`.

Comment: [`HINSTANCE`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.HINSTANCE.html) implements the `Default` trait. `HINSTANCE::default()` returns a default-constructed `HINSTANCE` value. The error you get is from the OS. Apparently, you cannot install a global `WH_MOUSE` hook without supplying the instance handle of the module containing the hook callback. Regardless, a hook is the most expensive way to monitor input. [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) is generally a better option.

Comment: @IInspectable Ahh, thanks, I'm stupid and didn't get what the error says, as you said it doesn't work with `WH_MOUSE`, but it works with `WH_MOUSE_LL`. I'll see into Raw Input you've mentioned, thanks!

Comment: Use `WH_MOUSE_LL` instead of `WH_MOUSE`.  Low-level hooks will deliver the data to your process.  High level hooks run a callback *inside the process which ordinarily receives the message*, which means the callback code has to be copied to that process, which is where the HMODULE gets involved.

Comment: For hooks that will be injected into another process, according to [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw#parameters), If *the `dwThreadId` parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the `lpfn` parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL*. And `hmod` is *A handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the `lpfn` parameter*.